# Error getting array length an throwing exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, methods

I'm currently having an issue with this function. I'm getting an error for the numSongs in getSongsArray(numSongs); saying that I need to throw an exception (unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declare to be thrown). Below is the instructions and the code I currently have. I'm just a girl whose been struggling on this for about 3 hours now and at this point I'm desperate.

**Instructions:**
Write a method called getSongsArray that takes an integer parameter (numSongs), 
returns an array of Strings, and is declared to throw an Exception. If the 
parameter passed is a negative value, throw an Exception. Otherwise,
loop numSongs times prompting the user to enter another name each pass through
the loop. Return this array of names.

Call getSongsArray passing the size of the array (any integer) that you want returned

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many songs would you like to enter?");
        int numSongs = scnr.nextInt();

        getSongsArray(numSongs);
    } //end main

    public static int getSongsArray(int numSongs) throws Exception 
    {
        if (numSongs <= 0) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Number");
        }
    } //end getSongsArray
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error-message?

Comment: Just added what the exact error message says :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java unreported exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091589/java-unreported-exception)

Comment: @Elizabeth, you've successfully completed 1/3 of your assignment.  In your existing method `getSongsArray` you need to change return type to int[].  You should keep on working and you'll succeed.  You may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326653/how-to-fill-an-array-with-int-numbers-using-a-loop-in-java) for the answer

Comment: @UnholySheep sadly no :( ive tried doing try catch exceptions and it results in more errors

Comment: @AlexRudenko can you clarify where to change return type to int[] im a little confused

Comment: Sorry, I meant change method signature to `private static String[] getSongsArray(int num)`

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that `getSongsArray` can throw an exception and that this isn't caught in your `main`-function.
The solution to this is simple: catch the error-message;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many songs would you like to enter?");
        int numSongs = scnr.nextInt();
        try {
            getSongsArray(numSongs);
        } catch (Exception e){ 
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    } //end main
```

But you're still going to have other problems, as you aren't completely done with your task. This post here only answeres the specific question about the `unreported exception` error!

Comment: If you encounter more errors, you should ask them in another question.